# Object destructing import from library

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Im trying to use object destructing imports in my code.

I would like to import only map and extend in my component.

Would I do

```
import { map, extend } from lodash;
```

How can I use it in my code?

Javascript also has a map, so if I do

```
let arr = [1,3,4];
arr.map((item) =>  console.log(item))
```

How can I refer to lodash map, not the actual map method?

PS: Im trying to understand object destructing methods. I know I can use ES6 map, this is just an example.

Comment: map(yourfunc).bind([1,2,3,4]);

Comment: Import syntax is not destructuring. It's creating aliases, no more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a **default import**.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
_.map(...);
```

This is a **named import**.

```
import { map } from 'lodash';
map(...);
```

Using `map()` as a method of the default import and as a standalone function are essentially the same (with the only meaningful difference being the [value of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method)). Which syntax works is up to the library you are importing. You can only use a default import if the library defines a default export and same for named imports / exports. Both can also be used at the same time, though this is a bit unusual.

The default import can be named whatever your heart desires. If you want to confuse people and pretend that Lodash is jQuery, you can do so.

```
`import $ from 'lodash';`
```

On the other hand, named imports have specific names that they are bound to. So unlike the default import, trying to use the named import syntax on `$` vs `_` refers to an entirely different object and will throw if not defined as an export within the library.

```
// These are very different.
import { $ } from 'lodash';
import { _ } from 'lodash';
```

If it becomes necessary, you can "rename" a named import.

```
import { map as crazyFunc } from 'lodash';
```

In the above case, `crazyFunc` can be named whatever your heart desires, but `map` must remain as-is, otherwise it will refer to an entirely different object and will throw if not defined as an export within the library.

It may help to understand that these are equivalent.

```
import { default as _ } from 'lodash';
import _ from 'lib';
```

The latter is simply sugar for the former. And the default export syntax is sugar for creating a named export with the name `default`.

For more info (including features not covered here), see [ES6 modules syntax](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html).

Full example:

```
import { map } from 'lodash';
const squares = map([4, 8], (n) => {
    return n * n;
});
console.log(squares);  // => [16, 64]
```